# Replacement has length zero in R

Tags: r, replace

I have this function that gives me the error: `1111Error in b[i] <- z : replacement has length zero`... I can't find why... any help will be welcomed :)

```
a <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:4), 4))
b <- numeric(256)

generating_numbers <- function() {
for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(a)) {
        z <- cat(a[i,j]) }
    b[i] <- z }
}

generating_numbers()
```

The aim here is to save the number combinations generated by `expand.grid` to a list in `b`. Everything works instead of changing the value of `b`.

Comment: Maybe you just wanted `apply(a,1,paste0,collapse = "")`?

Comment: Any reason why you are using `cat()` in the assignment?

Comment: if you want to understand why it doesn't work, consider this: `cat` does not return a value, it prints it on screen. What you are looking for was `paste0` (e.g. `z <- paste0(z,a[i,j])`)

Comment: With paste, b is 0 0 0 0 0 0... In other words, it doesn't solve the problem... :(

Comment: @Jealie not to mention that the posted code doesn't even do that - it just tries to *replace* `z` each time thru the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to keep the code essentially the same you would need something like:

```
a <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:4), 4))
b <- numeric(256)

generating_numbers <- function() {
for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    z <- paste(a[i,],collapse=" ") 
    b[i] <- z }
}

generating_numbers()
```

The second `for()` loop is unnecessary because you're trying to get the number combinations, so you don't want to iterate over each column...

...but you could probably accomplish the same thing in one line:

```
b <- apply(a,1,paste,collapse=" ")
```

...unless I misunderstood what you're trying to do.

**UPDATE:**

I missed the part about being in a list, so here's how you might keep them as tuples using a modified version of your code:

```
a <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:4), 4))

generating_numbers <- function() {
  b <- NULL
  for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    z <- a[i,] 
    b[[i]] <- as.numeric(z) }
  return(b)
}

generating_numbers()
```

...or you can take advantage of the fact that dataframes are lists like so:

```
b <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(a)))
```